# ¿Cómo obtener los usuarios que estan inscritos en el llamado 1 y 2?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo una tabla llamada inscripciones que cuenta con los siguientes campos

```
(idinscripcion,idusuario,idllamado)
```

[image: tabla inscripciones]

Un usuario puede estar inscripto en más de un llamado como se puede observar para el usuario con el id=5.

Necesito obtener solo los usuarios que estén inscriptos en ambos llamados

```
(idllamado=1 y idllamado=2)
```

Intente con esta consulta :

```
SELECT idusuario, count(*) 
from inscripciones 
where idllamado IN(1,2)
GROUP BY idusuario HAVING COUNT(*)>=2;
```

Pero resulta que esta consulta al parecer funciona como un OR, ya que devuelve aquellos usuarios que puedan estar inscriptos en el idllamado=1 y/o idllamado=2.

También intente con una unión, seleccionado los usuarios que estén en el llamado =1 y los que estén en el llamado = 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.idusuario FROM 
(SELECT distinct idusuario from inscripciones where idllamado =1
UNION
SELECT distinct idusuario from inscripciones where idllamado =2) u
ORDER BY idusuario ASC;
```

Pero de nuevo aquí el problema es que no se que usuario esta inscripto en los dos llamados.

Por favor, ¿podrían orientarme en como realizar la consulta?
Muchas gracias

**NOTA : Estoy trabajando con la versión 10.3.21 de mariadb.**

Comment: Podrías agregar tus tablas, y no como imágenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma podría ser agrupar por `idusuario` filtrando los `idllamado` esperados y contar los valores distintos de estos para terminar filtrando solo los que tienen los dos.

```
SELECT idusuario 
       FROM inscripciones
       WHERE idllamado IN (1,2)
       GROUP BY idusuario
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT idllamado) = 2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio tu respuesta resolvió mi consulta.